# Asp.net core add scaffolded, razor pages using entity framework: there was an error running the selected code generator

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor-pages

unfortunately I can not add a scaffolded item, especially with many too many relations.

I have three cases where I have problems.

**Case 1:** 
If i choos as "Data context class" my "OwnContext (Test.Model) [case 1 screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRyyW.png) 
I get the error message: There was an error running the selected code generator. No parameterless constructor defined for this object. [case 1 screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Smb.png)
**What am I doing wrong here? I would like to understand the problem.**

**Case 2:**
If i choose a new "Data context class" when I click on the icon with the plus sign. [case 2 screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpW6Z.png) and [case 2 screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ndLG.png)
I geht the error message: There was an error running the selected code generator: Entity type BookCategory has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API. [case 2 screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5wkx.png)

**I do not understand why this error message comes. Because I use the Fluent api to represent the many to many relationships.**

**My model for both cases (in the file Model.cs):**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Test.Model
{
    public class OwnContext : DbContext
    {
        public OwnContext(DbContextOptions<OwnContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Test.Model.Book> Book { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Test.Model.Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Test.Model.BookCategory> BookCategory { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasKey(c => new {c.BookId, c.CategoryId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasKey(c => c.BookId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c => c.CategoryId);
        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IList<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public IList<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**Case 3:**
If i removed the annotations [Key] and use this model [case 3 screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDDBn.png):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Test.Model
{
    public class OwnContext : DbContext
    {
        public OwnContext(DbContextOptions<OwnContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }


        public DbSet<Test.Model.Book> Book { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Test.Model.Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Test.Model.BookCategory> BookCategory { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasKey(c => new {c.BookId, c.CategoryId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasKey(c => c.BookId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c => c.CategoryId);
        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IList<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public IList<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookCategory
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I get the following error message: There was an error running the selected code generator: The entity type BookCategory requieres a primary key to defined. [case 3 screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rSKZ.png)

I do not understand the problem. Because I define a primary key with this code.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasKey(c => new {c.BookId, c.CategoryId});
```

**What am I doing wrong here? I would like to understand the problem.**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have an override section for your Fluent API:
[Warning from my own code: CS0114](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bv3Y.png)

"The only way to specify composite PKs to EF Core is with the fluent API." ( [Razor Pages with EF Core in ASP.NET Core - Data Model - 5 of 8 > Update the DB context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#update-the-db-context) )

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasKey(c => new {c.BookId, c.CategoryId});
}
```